# C# Parallel for loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I don't think I understand the Parallel for loop..
when I try this program

```
    Parallel.For(1, 20, i =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    });
```

it will spit out:

```
1
10
19
2
11
4
3
12
5
6
13
17
7
14
18
8
15
9
16
```

what I'm wanting to do is have a for loop threaded with a limit of 20 threads and make it print out like this,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.. ect

Comment: this is what it happens in a multithreaded environment. The threads are not running in the order you expect them to do. The solution is not to expect them to run in that order, or do not use a parallel for

Comment: So you want parallelism, but you want every operation to wait on the previous one?

Comment: @meJustAndrew got any suggestions on how I accomplish  do my task?

Comment: @CodeCaster I want the loop to run on their own thread

Comment: `Parallel.For` will create as many threads as is optimal for the computer running the code (e.g. 8 threads for a quad-core hyperthreaded CPU, but only 1 thread for a simple ARM device), you cannot set an absolute number of threads, but you can place a limit with the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` option.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is unclear. Explain very explicitly what exactly you want to happen, and why.

Comment: `AsParallel().Ordered()` might help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460719(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Ric I see, but how would I incorporate it with a forloop

Comment: Great documentation on this stuff: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460714(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

When you run a loop in parallel, you no longer have any guarantees on the ordering of the results. That's pretty much multi-threading 101 :)

If you need guaranteed ordering, avoid side-effects and order the results.